# Recursive loop not going back to position after recursive call

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm experimenting with recursive loops in Python 3.5 to store data from a testing software.

What I don't understand is why Python is not coming back to the first call of the recursive call and continue to loop.

### What am I willing to achieve?

I have an array of dictionaries as such:

```
testSuites = [{'id': '278', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}, {'id': '281', 'parent_id': '279', 'name': 'Screening'}, {'id': '279', 'parent_id': '278', 'name': 'Web'}, {'id': '282', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}]
```

I'd like to have one TestSuite object that would have an array of TestSuite children, each of them potentially having their own array of children (like a tree).

```
root (TestSuite, id=213)
    .array[ child1 (TestSuite, id=278), child2 (TestSuite, id=282) ]

child1 (TestSuite, id=278)
    .array[ child11 (TestSuite, id=279) ]

child11 (TestSuite, id=279)
    .array[ child111 (TestSuite, id=281) ]
```

With the twist that in the following case:

```
testSuites = [{'id': '278', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}, {'id': '281', 'parent_id': '279', 'name': 'Screening'}, {'id': '279', 'parent_id': '278', 'name': 'Web'}, {'id': '282', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'},  {'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '283'}, {'name': 'Screening', 'parent_id': '283', 'id': '284'}]
```

I'm expecting the following:

```
root (TestSuite, id=213)
    .array[ child1 (TestSuite, id=278), child2 (TestSuite, id=282), child3 (TestSuite, id=283) ]

child1 (TestSuite, id=278)
    .array[ child11 (TestSuite, id=279) ]

child11 (TestSuite, id=279)
    .array[ child111 (TestSuite, id=281) ]

child2 (TestSuite, id=282)
    .array[]

child3 (TestSuite, id=283)
    .array[ child31 (TestSuite, id=284) ]
```

I need them to be arrays (or something I can turn into arrays) because I need to feed the result to a library that can loop through arrays to fill in a document.

### My current code.

I have a simple `TestSuite` class which represents each node from the above graph:

```
class TestSuite:
    def __init__(self, testsuite_id = None):
            self.testsuite_id = testsuite_id
            self.hasChild = False
            self.child = None
```

I then use a function (I left the debug messages to understand the output I'm receiving) to loop in that array of dictionaries.

```
 1  def buildTestSuiteTree(parent, testSuites, loopDepth):
 2      print("[DEBUG] Entering in buildTestSuiteTree")
 3      print("[DEBUG] testSuites: {}".format(testSuites))
 4      print("[DEBUG] parent id: {}".format(parent.testsuite_id))
 5      print("[DEBUG] loopDepth: {}".format(loopDepth))
 6      tsChild = TestSuite()
 7      index = 0
 8      for testSuiteInfo in testSuites:
 9              print("[DEBUG] loopDepth: {}".format(loopDepth))
10              testSuiteInfo = decode(str(testSuiteInfo))
11              print("[DEBUG] testSuiteInfo: {}".format(testSuiteInfo))
12              print("[DEBUG] matching against parent id {}".format(parent.testsuite_id))
13              if  str(parent.testsuite_id) == testSuiteInfo['parent_id']:
14                      print("[DEBUG] FOUND mathing parent!")
15                      parent.hasChild = True
16                      parent.child = tsChild
17                      testSuites.pop(index)
18                      tsChild.testsuite_id = int(testSuiteInfo['id'])
19                      loopDepth += 1
20                      tsChild.child = buildTestSuiteTree(tsChild, testSuites, loopDepth)
21              index += 1
22      return tsChild
```

I already know that this won't give me the last bit of the above graph (`child (id = 282)`) because I'll need to use some array for each child, but that's not my issue at the moment :-)
`loopDepth` was my attempt to try to understand my issue.

### Output

```
>>> root = TestSuite()
>>> root.testsuite_id = 213
>>> t = buildTestSuiteTree(root, testSuites,0)
[DEBUG] Entering in buildTestSuiteTree
[DEBUG] testSuites: [{'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '278'}, {'name': 'Screening', 'parent_id': '279', 'id': '281'}, {'name': 'Web', 'parent_id': '278', 'id': '279'}, {'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '282'}]
[DEBUG] parent id: 213
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 0
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 0
[DEBUG] testSuiteInfo: {'id': '278', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}
[DEBUG] matching against parent id: 213
[DEBUG] FOUND mathing parent!
[DEBUG] Entering in buildTestSuiteTree
[DEBUG] testSuites: [{'name': 'Screening', 'parent_id': '279', 'id': '281'}, {'name': 'Web', 'parent_id': '278', 'id': '279'}, {'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '282'}]
[DEBUG] parent id: 278
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 1
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 1
[DEBUG] testSuiteInfo: {'id': '281', 'parent_id': '279', 'name': 'Screening'}
[DEBUG] matching against parent id: 278
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 1
[DEBUG] testSuiteInfo: {'id': '279', 'parent_id': '278', 'name': 'Web'}
[DEBUG] matching against parent id: 278
[DEBUG] FOUND mathing parent!
[DEBUG] Entering in buildTestSuiteTree
[DEBUG] testSuites: [{'name': 'Screening', 'parent_id': '279', 'id': '281'}, {'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '282'}]
[DEBUG] parent id: 279
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 2
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 2
[DEBUG] testSuiteInfo: {'id': '281', 'parent_id': '279', 'name': 'Screening'}
[DEBUG] matching against parent id: 279
[DEBUG] FOUND mathing parent!
[DEBUG] Entering in buildTestSuiteTree
[DEBUG] testSuites: [{'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '282'}]
[DEBUG] parent id: 281
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 3
[DEBUG] loopDepth: 3
[DEBUG] testSuiteInfo: {'id': '282', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}
[DEBUG] matching against parent id: 281
```

### My issue

I was expecting that once Python got to the point where there was no matching item in line 13 because it got to the lowest point of the recursive loop, it would go back "up" in `loopDepth` to the point of coming back to the "original" line 20.

From there, I would expect Python to continue to loop on the original loop with the `testSuites` being at that point:

```
testSuites: [{'name': 'Initial release', 'parent_id': '213', 'id': '282'}]
```

Then, having `t.child` being overwritten with the last value of `testSuites`.

What I see from the output is none of that!

I see that somehow Python stays at the lowest loop depth and try to match the parent ID which it doesn't find (it's stuck with the last child) and then... well, nothing.

I know that it's probably not the cleanest code or pythonesque ever, and I could maybe use some tree-like library to do the job (and maybe I'll get to that point), but I cannot understand why my program is behaving like expected.

1. Could you please show me the light and tell me why and where my code is faulty?
2. Bonus question: each child which has a child doesn't have their property `hasChild`set to yes. I'm guessing that it's due to the context where it's updated which is inside another function call, but could you confirm that this is it?

Thank you all for your attention!

## UPDATE

Thanks to Eric's comment, I removed the slicing of the array and it does improve the execution of the code. Here is the revised code (I also modified TestSuite to add the `array` property):

```
def buildTestSuiteTree(parent, testSuites, loopDepth):
    tsChild = TestSuite()
    index = 0
    for testSuiteInfo in testSuites:
            testSuiteInfo = decode(str(testSuiteInfo))
            if  str(parent.testsuite_id) == testSuiteInfo['parent_id']:
                    parent.hasChild = True
                    tsChild.testsuite_id = int(testSuiteInfo['id'])
                    loopDepth += 1
                    tsChild.child = buildTestSuiteTree(tsChild, testSuites, loopDepth)
                    parent.array.append(tsChild)
            index += 1
    return tsChild
```

When giving the initial `testSuites` it does a fine job creating a first level object with an array of children.
So it gives (this is a simplified representation):

```
root (TestSuite, id=213)
    .array[ child1 (TestSuite, id=278), child2 (TestSuite, id=282) ]

child1 (TestSuite, id=278)
    .array[ child11 (TestSuite, id=279) ]

child11 (TestSuite, id=279)
    .array[ child111 (TestSuite, id=281) ]
```

But when I give the complex data:

```
testSuites = [{'id': '278', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}, {'id': '281', 'parent_id': '279', 'name': 'Screening'}, {'id': '279', 'parent_id': '278', 'name': 'Web'}, {'id': '282', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'}]
```

The first level of children is all wrong:

```
root (TestSuite, id=213)
    .array[ child1 (TestSuite, id=283), child2 (TestSuite, id=283), child3 (TestSuite, id=283) ]

child1 (TestSuite, id=283)
    .array[ child11 (TestSuite, id=279) ]

child11 (TestSuite, id=279)
    .array[ child111 (TestSuite, id=281) ]

child12 (TestSuite, id=284)
    .array[]

child2 (TestSuite, id=283)
    .array[ child21 (TestSuite, id=279) ]

child21 (TestSuite, id=279)
    .array[ child211 (TestSuite, id=281) ]

child22 (TestSuite, id=284)
    .array[]

child3 (TestSuite, id=283)
    .array[ child31 (TestSuite, id=279) ]

child31 (TestSuite, id=279)
    .array[ child311 (TestSuite, id=281) ]

child32 (TestSuite, id=284)
    .array[]
```

(it's not a typo, it's three times the same objects...)

I have also updated my "What am I willing to achieve" because I think I wasn't clear on my final intentions and Poolka's answer doesn't cover it (or at least I can't make it fit my needs :-)).

Comment: This might not solve your problem, but you're modifying testSuites in your function and sending the same list into the recursed function. This is likely to have unexpected consequences when the inner recursion modifies the testSuites list. I'd suggest not modifying it at all and specify an index to use maybe? I didn't look at your requirements closely, so I'm not sure if that'll work for your case.

Comment: Hello. First af all, your question is a little bit messy now. You have changed a lot in the code but, for example, you did not provide updated version of `TestSuite` class. It does not change a lot since the problem is the same - you use recursion in a wrong way. It is so called XY problem I guess. The issue in the question can be solved with a single loop. And you have solved it with a loop implemented using recursion. You removed `testSuites.pop(index)` and now you iterate over `testSuites` list on every recursive step. The greater the size of `testSuites` list the more replications you get.

Comment: You're right, it starts to be messy, I'll reflect on what you wrote and close this one and open another one if needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you`'d like to have an object that would go from the root to the last child like this ...`. But the data is stored in a list so you don't know all the childs for every parent. So you iterate over `testSuites` list on every recursive step. Inside the loop you treat the first element of `testSuites` list, pop it from the list and make recursive call with the modified list which is `testSuites[1:]`. So you implemented looping through recursion. Don't do that. It is wierd and very ineffective.

This is how I would try to solve the problem in the question. `func1()` is used to create dictionary of all `TestSuite` objects. `func2()` is a recursive function used to print `TestSuite` objects in a manner you provided in the question.

```
class TestSuite:

    def __init__(self, testsuite_id):
            self.testsuite_id = testsuite_id
            self.hasChild = False
            self.childs = set()

    def __repr__(self):
        str_1 = (
            'TestSutie({})'
            .format(self.testsuite_id))
        str_2 = (
            ' with childs {}'
            .format([child.testsuite_id for child in self.childs])
            if self.hasChild
            else ' with NO childs')
        return str_1 + str_2


def func1(testSuites):

    answer = dict()

    for suite in testSuites:
        if suite['id'] not in answer:
            answer[suite['id']] = TestSuite(suite['id'])
        if suite['parent_id'] not in answer:
            answer[suite['parent_id']] = TestSuite(suite['parent_id'])
        answer[suite['parent_id']].hasChild = True
        answer[suite['parent_id']].childs.add(answer[suite['id']])

    return answer


def func2(root, num=0):

    print('|   ' * num, end='')
    print('id = ', root.testsuite_id)

    for child in root.childs:
        print('|   ' * (num + 1))
        func2(child, num + 1)


testSuites = [
        {'id': '278', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'},
        {'id': '281', 'parent_id': '279', 'name': 'Screening'},
        {'id': '279', 'parent_id': '278', 'name': 'Web'},
        {'id': '282', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'},
        {'id': '283', 'parent_id': '213', 'name': 'Initial release'},
        {'id': '284', 'parent_id': '283', 'name': 'Screening'}]

answer = func1(testSuites)
print(*answer.values(), sep='\n')
print()
func2(root=answer['213'])
```

Output:

```
TestSutie(213) with childs ['283', '278', '282']
TestSutie(278) with childs ['279']
TestSutie(281) with NO childs
TestSutie(279) with childs ['281']
TestSutie(282) with NO childs
TestSutie(283) with childs ['284']
TestSutie(284) with NO childs

id =  213
|   
|   id =  278
|   |   
|   |   id =  279
|   |   |   
|   |   |   id =  281
|   
|   id =  282
|   
|   id =  283
|   |   
|   |   id =  284
```